# The method getCastTypeName(int) is undefined for the type Dialect

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm getting this error for the application that uses `Hibernate` I need to work with:

```
The method getCastTypeName(int) is undefined for the type Dialect
```

It looks like I am using the wrong version of `Hibernate`.

What version of does have this method in `Dialect`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hibernate 4.1` (which seems to be the latest version) has it:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/

So does every version from `3.2` and up, see for yourself:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/

Version `3.2` is over 3 years old, which version is the application using? If it is a really old version perhaps the method could be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I searched on Google for "java Dialect". The second result linked to the API documentation for Hibernate 3.5. There I found this:

[https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#getCastTypeName(int)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#getCastTypeName%28int%29)

This suggests that Hibernate 3.5 provided a method called "getCastTypeName" which takes an int.